# Three.js CSSObject3D how to get object's width

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Ok so firstly I dynamically great HTML Dom Elements from HTML text, I use this function

```
String.prototype.toDomElement = function () {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = "toDomWrapper";
  wrapper.innerHTML = this;

  return wrapper;
};
```

to "create a dom element":

```
var element = obj.html.toDomElement();
```

From which I then create a CSS3DObject:

```
var cssElement = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
```

after placing a couple of these (divs) on the canvas - I would like to lay them out (the absolute positions, which I know how to do), however I have no clue as to how to get the width of each element?!

I can't predetermine the width - they are being dynamically generated.

Help would be VERY MUCH appreciated - I've tried going through all of the three.js CSS3D examples:
       http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_periodictable
and I've really searched the web - couldn't find anything - in every example they set the width of an element.style.width or its retrieved from the css.

anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.appendChild(element);
var cssElement = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
```

and now you can get the element's properties

```
var el = $("#"+element.id);
var w = el.width();
var h = el.height();
var x = el.position().left;
var y = el.position().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
var cssElement = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
var width = cssElement.element.style.width;
```

Comment: I did try this actually, doesn't work... thanks for the suggestion though :) In the end I figured it out - what you have to do is add element to the document: document.appendChild(element); and then query the width! It seems that only after the element is added to the actual document - it actually acquires properties...